# Timestamp in Cell when any cell in row is edited

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm an absolute rookie - so I appreciate any insight/ suggestions on where I'm (obviously going wrong)

I have a sheet where I'm trying to get a date stamp in column B when the same row is edited (apart from column B) I would like the date stamp to be in the same row as the row that's being edited.

I've had a bash at the script (and failed)

I have 2 x onEdit functions, so the trigger would have to be myFunction etc

Below is the attempted script:

FYI - the data in the sheet is from column B11 to AQ

```
function myFunction(e)
{
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Position Activity'); //
{
var actRng = sheet.getActiveRange();
var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
var rowIndex = actRng.getRowIndex();
var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf(1) + 1;
var orderCol = headers[0].indexOf(23) + 1;
if (dateCol > 0 && rowIndex > 1 && e.range.columnStart > 1)
{
  sheet.getRange(rowIndex, dateCol).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "CET", 
"dd-mmm-yyyy"));
}
}
```

}

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Simple Trigger `onEdit()` and use that event to get which range is edited and from which sheet, you can also get new value and old value.

**Below is the sample code:**

```
   function onEdit(e){       
      var editedRange = e.range; // Using Object e to get the range
      var r = editedRange.getRow() // row which is edited
      var c = editedRange.getColumn() // column which is edited
      var wsName = editedRange.getSheet()
      if(wsName.getName() === "Position Activity" && c !== 2) // skipping column B
     {       
        wsName.getRange(r, 2).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "CET", 
                                       "dd-mmm-yyyy")) // Adding Date in column b
    
      }
    }
```

**Reference:**

[onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite)

[Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Comment: Thanks for this and taking the time to look at this - it worked initially, then it suggests e is undefined. It's likely something I've done but do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Try editing the sheet and look into execution log and also remove the existing edit trigger you've set.